# load_model("test.mod",True/False,False) giving me a ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Tags: python, keras

Im trying to save my deep learning model and be able to load it.  When I try to load it I get the following error
load_model("test.mod",True/False,False)
I have the following test code:

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
import keras

## load data set

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist  # mnist is a dataset of 28x28 images of handwritten digits and their labels
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()  # unpacks images to x_train/x_test and labels to y_train/y_test

## normlize it

x_train = x_train/255.0
x_test = x_test/255.0

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_train[0].shape)

model = Sequential()

## explain input shape

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))

## what does drop out do????

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy'],
)

model.fit(x_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=3,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

model.save("test.mod")

from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model("test.mod",True/False,False)

Comment: Why are you doing this? True/False

Comment: Please share the entire error message, and fix the formatting of your post. It isn't clear to me what the issue is, since you're the one who wrote `True/False`, and I don't know what the expected result was.